# How to bind object data from Combobox to ListBox

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox

This is the custom object:

```
public class FileItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

`Collection`:

```
public ObservableCollection<FileItem> collection { get; set; }
```

`Combobox`:

```
<ComboBox
    Name="cbCollection" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding interfaces}"/>
```

`ListBox`:

```
    <ListBox 
        Name="lbCollection "
        ItemsSource="{Binding collection}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

So my `Combobox` is populated with my `object` collection and i want to see all its properties in my `ListBox`.

Currently:

1. I can see only the property `Name`.
2. i can see all the objects from my `Combobox` and not only the selected one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see more than just the name property, you'll need to extend the data template to include the additional properties.

If you want to see the selected item's properties, then you should bind to the combo box's `SelectedItem` property. Actually I don't think you want a `ListBox` as there is only one selected item.

This should get you started:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ElementName=cbCollection, Path=SelectedItem}">
  <ContentControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FileItem}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: Where i need to put this ContentControl ?

Comment: Replace your ListBox with it.

Comment: Error 5 Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: dataType and Error 6 All objects added to an IDictionary must have a Key attribute or some other type of key associated with them.

Comment: Still error: cannot find my object memeber (Name) in my namespace